# Finding the index of a queue that holds a member of a containing object for a given value

Tags: c#, queue

I have a Queue that contains a collection of objects, one of these objects is a class called GlobalMarker that has a member called GlobalIndex.

What I want to be able to do is find the index of the queue where the GlobalIndex contains a given value (this will always be unique).

Simply using the `Contains` method shown below returns a `bool`. How can I obtain the queue index of this match?

```
RealTimeBuffer
  .OfType<GlobalMarker>()
  .Select(o => o.GlobalIndex)
  .Contains(INT_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need the index then perhaps you are using the wrong collection type.  A queue is not designed to support random access (like an array or a `List<T>`).  If you need random access then perhaps you should be using a type that implements `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Queue's don't provide an interface that returns the index of a matching element, neither, unfortunately does LINQ.**

You may want to consider using a `List<>` or `Array` if you need such methods. However, it is possible to treat the Queue as an IEnumerable and roll your own implementation - alternatively you could create a List from the queue and use `IndexOf`:

```
RealTimeBuffer.OfType<GlobalMarker>()
              .Select(o => o.GlobalIndex).ToList().IndexOf( INT_VALUE );
```

Answer (score 0):

If all Items in your collection are of type `GlobalMarker`, it is better to use  `ILis<>`

```
 List<GlobalMarker> RealTimeBuffer = new List<GlobalMarker>();
 GlobalMarker globalMarker = 
        RealTimeBuffer.SingleOrDefault(o => o.GlobalIndex == 1);
```

If they are not All the same Type, You may use `IList`, but keep in mind, It is not a recommended approach. Here is a sample which will return `GlobalMarker` object

```
   ArrayList RealTimeBuffer = new ArrayList();
   RealTimeBuffer.Add(new GlobalMarker(){ GlobalIndex = 3 });
   GlobalMarker globalMarker = 
   RealTimeBuffer.OfType<GlobalMarker>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.GlobalIndex == INT_VALUE);
```